# How to change the size of a picture after inserting it into a word document

Tags: c#, image, interop, ms-word, resize

I'm adding a picture to a word document at a certain bookmark.  However, the picture is too big and is forcing text off the page, so I need to be able to change the size of the picture after it is in the word document.

Comment: Seems pretty off-topic for StackOverflow - unless you're asking how to resize the picture programmatically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you insert the image, it should return you an InlineShape, which you can modify:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\SomeUserName\Desktop\Doc1.docx");

var shape = doc.Bookmarks["PicHere"].Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\SomePicture\Pictures\1234.JPG", false, true);
shape.Width = 150;
shape.Height = 150;
app.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. I could not figure that one out for some reason. I'm gonna go bang my head against a wall now..

Answer (score 1):

Code, which I used to resize the picture successfully is:

```
var shape = headerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(tempLogoPathName, true, true).ConvertToShape();
shape.HeightRelative = 10f;
shape.WidthRelative = 40f;
```

Seems that convering to Shape is the solution. Previous set the different height directly in InLineShapes, produced an error.
(I just edited a post and simplified the code, so it does not use 2nd dll library: Microsoft.Office.Core anymore)

Comment: Is this an answer or a question or both? If you need to ask something related please make a new question instead appending questions to your answer.