# How to add an image at a specific location in MSWord Using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

How do I add an image at a specific co-ordinate of the Word documents.

I have been searching for a while, but unsuccessful in finding a solution for this problem.

**EDIT
Currently using :**

```
    oDoc.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\MHD\Desktop\retouche.bmp");
    oDoc.Application.Selection.MoveDown(word.WdUnits.wdScreen, 2);
```

**Problem:**

[image]

**What is needed:**

[image]

So the image should be located at the bottom right corner of the last page in the document.

Comment: It would be pretty sweet if you could show us some code.

Comment: there i added them thaniks :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inserting a inline shape which is positioned within the text. You may want to insert as a normal shape, which can be positioned anywhere above the text:

```
oDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(
    @"C:\Users\MHD\Desktop\retouche.bmp",
    null, null,
    left, top, width, height)
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do that is:

- open your word document > add a bookmark named: "PicHere"
- and then [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483471/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-picture-after-inserting-it-into-a-word-document)