# How to C# Adjust picture size Docx

Tags: c#, image, size, addition, docx

I use the following code to add a Picture but i dont adjust image size

```cs
var myImageFullPath = "ex.jpg";

using (DocX document = DocX.Create("ex.docx"))
{
    Image image = document.AddImage(myImageFullPath);
    Picture picture = image.CreatePicture();
    Paragraph title = document.InsertParagraph().Append("TEST");
    title.Alignment = Alignment.center;        
    Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();
    p1.AppendPicture(picture);                
    document.Save();
}
```

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483471/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-picture-after-inserting-it-into-a-word-document/8483620) might help you to adjust image size...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED THX
Picture picture = image.CreatePicture(400,600);